# how to write RDF domain and range restriction based on property value rather than class

Tags: rdf, owl

I have the following case which I'm trying write an RDF/OWL rule for. The goal is to improve consistency checking in the resulting data base.

I have a class called "Expression" and a class called "Manifestation", they can be related by "hasManifestation".

It easy to enough to restrict the domain and range accordingly so that the domain of "hasManifestation" is "Expression" and the Range is "Manifestation".

But I want to go one step further.

Expressions and Manifestation have a property called structure level, level 1, 2, 3, 4

So an Expression at level 1 should always be related through "hasManifestation" to a "Manifestation" also at level 1, never at level 2, 3, etc.

Likewise an Expression at level 2 should always be related to a Manifestation at level 2 never at level 1 or 3, etc.

So I want write a rule for the Domain and Range of "hasManifestation" that goes something like the following:

Range: Y must be a Manifestation and if the value of the Domain is level Z, then  Y must be  level Z

Domain: X must be an Expression and if the value of the Range is level Z, then X is level X.

I think I can write this in predicate logic as follows: E = expression, M=manifestation, L=level, R=Range, D=Domain

Range: `y(My and (xz)(Dx and Lxz) -> (Lyz))`

Domain: `x(Ex and (yz)(Ry and Lyz) -> (Lxz))`

I might be messing that up somewhere, but hopefully you get the idea of what I would like to do.
But how could I write this as an OWL statement in ttl.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: just use SWRL and you're done

Comment: So instead of trying to write this rule in the ontology itself, just provide the reasoner with an extra set of rules in SWRL? Might you give man example for the rule I want in SWRL?

Comment: I've written something like the following in protege expression(?a) ^ hasManifestation(?a, ?man) ^ hasLevel(?a, ?level) -> hasLevel(?man, ?level) which seems to work to correctly infer the Manifestation level, but protege doesn't give any errors if you set an inconsistent level, for example manually setting the Manifestation level to 2 when it should be 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `hasValue` restrictions to express this, but not at the domain and range level of the property - restricting it on the property requires a property for each level.

So, you could create a general concept inclusion axiom, along the lines of:

```
(<urn:test:Expression> and (<urn:test:hasLevel> value 1)) subclassOf
    (<urn:test:hasManifestation> some (<urn:test:Manifestation> and (<urn:test:hasLevel> value 1)))
```

(example rewritten in Manchester Syntax - GCIs cannot actually be written in this syntax but it's easier to read)

In Functional syntax, the axiom looks like this:

```
SubClassOf(
    ObjectIntersectionOf(
           Expression
           DataHasValue(hasLevel "1"^^xsd:integer)
    )
    ObjectSomeValuesFrom(hasManifestation
           ObjectIntersectionOf(
                   Manifestation
                   DataHasValue(hasLevel "1"^^xsd:integer)
            )
    )
)
```

In Turtle:

```
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
[ rdf:type owl:Ontology] .
<urn:test:hasManifestation> rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .
<urn:test:hasLevel> rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty .
<urn:test:Expression> rdf:type owl:Class .
<urn:test:Manifestation> rdf:type owl:Class .
[ owl:intersectionOf ( <urn:test:Expression>
                   [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                     owl:onProperty <urn:test:hasLevel> ;
                     owl:hasValue 1
                   ]
                 ) ;
  rdf:type owl:Class ;
  rdfs:subClassOf [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
          owl:onProperty <urn:test:hasManifestation> ;
          owl:someValuesFrom [ owl:intersectionOf ( <urn:test:Manifestation>
                               [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                 owl:onProperty <urn:test:hasLevel> ;
                                 owl:hasValue 1
                               ]) ;
                      rdf:type owl:Class
                    ]
          ]
] .
```

If you choose to use multiple properties, it's easier to declare domains and ranges but you have to use multiple properties:

```
hasManifestation1 domain exist hasLevel (hasValue 1)
hasManifestation1 range exist hasLevel (hasValue 1)
```

and so on (no need to modify existing domain and range expressions as multiple axioms are already implying intersection of the class expressions).

Comment: thanks so much. I think it was the 2nd option that I really wanted to avoid. It seems annoying and redundant to make a new property for each level. So I like the first solution better. I think understand most of it, but I confused about the use of "subClassOf". What is being declared to be a subClassOf  what in this axiom? Also if you have time, would you be willing to show me what that axiom my look in an TTL syntax? Do I need to use OWL:Restriction for example?

Comment: General Concept Inclusion or GCI for short means that there are class expressions on both sides of the `subClassOf` term - it's a regular subclass axiom, structurally, the only difference is that there isn't an IRI for the left hand side. They have important implications in reasoning performance and in readability of the ontology, so you could choose to define an IRI for the left hand side instead.

Comment: the use of `owl:Restriction` is a purely syntactic constraint for Turtle and RDF/XML, as you can see it does not appear in other syntaxes.

Comment: I found this helpful post on GCI's :) @Ignazio Thanks for your help and the extended example.

Comment: Should I expect Protege's reasoner to be able to enforce this axiom? I think I've implemented correctly the GCI, but if I change one of the hasLevel value to 2, the Protege reasoner doesn't complain of an inconsistency.  (If Protege should be complaining, I'll create a new question with screen shots)

Comment: The axiom doesn't impose that an individual only has one value for the level; to get an inconsistency I believe for all restrictions must also be added. I haven't gone as far as testing what will happen in an actual ontology.